# How to install ffmpeg on shared hosting?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, server, cpanel

I am using shared hosting and installed a PHP script there. This script needs FFmpeg (recommended version 3.0+) to work. But I don't know how to install it on shared hosting. I have searched on youtube, they are showing, download the FFmpeg file from ffmpeg.org then set the path inside the script. but that's not working for me. FFmpeg needs to be installed on my server to make this script work.

**My server info:**

Hosting Package:    undefined

Server Name:    server

cPanel Version: 92.0 (build 6)

Apache Version: 2.4.46

PHP Version:    7.3.23

MySQL Version:  5.7.33-cll-lve

Architecture:   x86_64

Operating System:   linux

Shared IP Address:  161.97.101.164

Path to Sendmail:   /usr/sbin/sendmail

Path to Perl:   /usr/bin/perl

Perl Version:   5.16.3

Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64

I have tried to run some command VIA terminal of my hosting, but whatever command I type, it says that "command not found".
[image]

so now tell me guys, how can I install FFmpeg on my server?

Comment: Ask your provider first if it is possible at all.

Comment: [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), extract `ffmpeg` from the `tar.xz` file, move `ffmpeg` into `/usr/local/bin`. See dupe links above.

Comment: No sane shared host will permit you to run ffmpeg for long. "Abuse of resources".

Comment: @llogan kindly first take a look at this photo, https://ibb.co/1vgXbxc this is a screenshot of my path configuration. There is no usr dir in this script, but still it shows  this path "usr/local/bin/php" but as I didn’t find usr dir anywhere inside the script, so I had created usr/bin folder and uploaded ffmpeg inside that. But it seems to me doesn’t working because like the photo this script keep showing that warning sign instead of green tik. And also can you tell me with ffmpeg I should download? There are many file inside your given link.

Comment: @ceejayoz why not? I pay for this to them. And also I have unlimited bandwidth plan.

Comment: @R.H.Tasin Why does Netflix pay millions of dollars a year for bandwidth when they could just buy one shared hosting "unlimited" bandwidth plans? Hint: It's not *actually* unlimited. Shared hosts run many, many people on one server. If you use too many resources, they'll cut you off... and ffmpeg uses a *lot* of resources.

Comment: @ceejayoz I wanna make a website where people can watch and download videos. What kind of server will be best for it? I can not afford dedicated or VPS hosting. Do cloud hosting has ffmpeg? how to check if it has?

Comment: @R.H.Tasin Whatever you're using is looking for ffmpeg in `/usr/bin`, so put `ffmpeg` in there if you are unable to change the script or if the script does not pay attention to your `PATH`. Download `ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz`.